# Resize layout to get into other layout

Tags: android, layout, size

I created a menuView.xml layout to be in all of the layouts of my activity. This layout has one column on each border and a title bar like this:

[ComposeView http://img845.imageshack.us/img845/2121/d6zp.png](http://img845.imageshack.us/img845/2121/d6zp.png)

I insert this layout in the other layouts this way:

```
<!-- Show menu -->
<com.example.MenuView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

But if one of the layouts has full screen view, part of this view gets covered by the MenuView, so...

How could I tell to this view to adapt its size to the blank space inside the MenuView to not get covered by it?

**UPDATE -- full XML included**

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:background="@drawable/degradado">


    <!-- Show menu -->
    <com.example.MenuView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/Left_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"        
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    //Here go buttons, views, etc...

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/Right_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"        
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" > 

    //Here go buttons, views, etc...

</RelativeLayout>
```

What happens here is that these 2 Relative layouts get covered by the MenuView (The darkest gre borders and the top black bar), and the ideal way would be that these 2 layouts get fitted to the blank space (the clearest gray).

I can solve this setting margin sizes to the Relative layouts to fit inside of it, but i know this is not the best way to do it, so I don't know if there is another way.

Comment: i'm sorry, with my android knowledge i can't find a better way to do this. I'm gonna delete my old answer because it's useless. I hope someone posts an answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to solve your issue is with inheritance.
If you define an Activity that can be used as a template for all your fleshed out Activitys to add their content to.
I don't know what you custom menu is 'made of' but as a simple example:

Create a basic Activity with code:

```
  public class ActivityWithMenu extends Activity 
  {
      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
      {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_with_menu_layout);
      }
  }
```

and xml:

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"    
tools:context=".ActivityWithMenu" >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dip"  
    android:background="#ff000000"  
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"    
    android:text="Main Menu Title Bar"
    android:id="@+id/mainmenutitle" />
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="20dip"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mainmenutitle"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="#ff999999"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/lefthandmenu" />
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="20dip"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mainmenutitle"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="#ff999999"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/righthandmenu" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/righthandmenu"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lefthandmenu"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mainmenutitle"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/activitycontent"
    />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Then create your xml for a specific Activity, in this case a simple 'Hello World' layout:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scrollbars="vertical" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff00ff00"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        />
</LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
```

But now when you write the code for this Activity, extend 'ActivityWithMenu' instead of the Activity class direct and inflate this xml layout as follows:

```
  public class Activity1 extends ActivityWithMenu
  {
      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
      {
          requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
          getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,    
                  WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);    

          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

          LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.activitycontent);

          ScrollView sv = (ScrollView)this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity1_layout, ll, false);

          ll.addView(sv);
      }
  }
```

I have added the code for making the Activity fullscreen here instead of in the parent ActivityWithMenu class assuming that you wouldn't want them all displayed that way but you could move it into the parent class if appropriate.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've got a layout called `menu_view` where I have desgined the menu wich is formed by 2 columns with buttons on the laterals, and a custom title bar. Then, a class called `menuView` too where I define all the button's onClickListeners, but this class `extends RelativeLayout`. here i use the layout inflater, and then to insert this menu on other layouts I simply define it on the wanted layout. I see that you say to extend this menu class as an activity, but is this compatible with what I'm doing?

Comment: I don't see why not, after a little bit of a re-structure.  If you change my 'lefthandmenu'/'righthandmenu' with the layout xml for your columns of buttons and the 'mainmenutitle' with your title xml, just leave the arrangement properties like 'toLeftOf' etc and it should display the same.  And move your onClickListener setup into the onCreate of the parent class ('ActivityWithMenu' in my example) and that way you need only have it in one place.  I do think it will be easier doing it this way rather than trying to overlay such a complex interface control over every activity ad-hoc.

Comment: Finally tried this way but I'm having one problem, it makes an error and the logcat say that the error is when inflating the "ActivityWithMenu" layout. It tells me that it makes that error in "ScrollView sv = (ScrollView)this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity1_layout, ll, false);"

Comment: What is the error? I am assuming you have kept the file naming the same as my example? Are they all definately correct? ie. ll and sv are not coming out as null or anything?