# Inflate layout inside LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

In the app that I'm developing, I have a Menu with icons that is on the right and left edges of the screen, and it mantains there in all the app's activities.

What I've done is first create the "MenuView" class (wich may extend View, RelativeLayout, or something else)where are defined all the menu's icons and their onClickListeners. Then the layout for this class. In the layout I stablished 2 linearlayout's wich are each one on the border's of the screen (These refers to the menu) and a LinearLayout with the blank space inside the columns, where the other activities must go.

**MenuViewActivity.java**

```
public class MenuViewActivity extends {

public MenuViewActivity(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    ...

    ((ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.navButton)).setOnClickListener(launch_nav);

    final OnClickListener launch_nav = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getBaseContext().startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), Navigation.class));
        }
    };
    ...
```

**menu_view.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout     
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
tools:context="com.example.MenuViewActivity" >


<!-- Shows custom time titlebar -->
<include 
    layout="@layout/custom_tittlebar" >
</include>


<!-- Button columns -->    
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/lefthandmenu"
    android:layout_width="85dip"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/title"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"       
    android:background="@drawable/border_cut" >

    <ImageView
        ... />
    ...
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/righthandmenu"
    android:layout_width="85dip"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/title"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/border_cut" >

    <ImageView
        ... />
    ...        
</LinearLayout>

<!-- Blank space which will contain other activities -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/activitycontent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/righthandmenu"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lefthandmenu"
    android:layout_below="@id/title"
    android:orientation="vertical" >    
</LinearLayout>
```

So, what I must do now is to tell the program that other activities must go inside this last layout. For this, I do this in for example the Main class. **I inflate the layout.**

**MainClass.java**

```
public class MainClass extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    LinearLayout inside_menu_view = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.activitycontent);
    View this_layout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main, inside_menu_view);
    inside_menu_view.addView(this_layout);
```

But I'm getting an error on the logcat:

**UPDATE - After modifications still not working, this is the LogCat**

```
10-31 09:35:17.521: E/AndroidRuntime(1676): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-31 09:35:17.521: E/AndroidRuntime(1676): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.MainClass}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class com.example.MenuViewActivity
10-31 09:35:17.521: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
10-31 09:35:17.521: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
10-31 09:35:17.521: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
10-31 09:35:17.521: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
10-31 09:35:17.521: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-31 09:35:17.521: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
10-31 09:35:17.521: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10-31 09:35:17.521: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-31 09:35:17.521: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-31 09:35:17.521: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-31 09:35:17.521: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-31 09:35:17.521: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-31 09:35:17.521: E/AndroidRuntime(1676): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #12: Error inflating class com.example.MenuViewActivity
10-31 09:35:17.521: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
10-31 09:35:17.521: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
10-31 09:35:17.521: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
10-31 09:35:17.521: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
10-31 09:35:17.521: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
10-31 09:35:17.521: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
10-31 09:35:17.521: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     at com.masermic.medialauncher.LauncherActivity.onCreate(LauncherActivity.java:67)
10-31 09:35:17.521: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-31 09:35:17.521: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
10-31 09:35:17.521: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     ... 11 more
10-31 09:35:17.521: E/AndroidRuntime(1676): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
10-31 09:35:17.521: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
10-31 09:35:17.521: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
10-31 09:35:17.521: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
10-31 09:35:17.521: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     ... 19 more
10-31 09:35:17.521: E/AndroidRuntime(1676): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-31 09:35:17.521: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     at com.mexample.MenuViewActivity.<init>(MenuViewActivity.java:55)
10-31 09:35:17.521: E/AndroidRuntime(1676):     ... 22 more
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not inflate `Activity`. You can inflate `View` and derived type. So, your class should extends `View`, `ViewGroup` or some of the derived classes.

EDIT:

Regardins your inflate exception, you are getting a NPE at line 55 of your custom view, probably because, `R.id.navButton` is not declared inside the layout your a trying to inflate.

Comment: You say to change to `public class MenuViewActivity extends View` but then in `public class MainClass extends Activity`

Comment: please, also update your question with changes that you made to your code

Comment: would you like to have MenuViewActivity as root for your layout?

Comment: Sorry @blackbelt I don't understand what you mean with root for the layout. What I need is to have first the MenuViewActivity where I define the Menu's buttons, then the layout for this Menu class. And inside this layout set the space where will fit all other activities like MainClass. Basically, the idea is to fit all other layouts inside the espace between the 2 menubars, becouse if I don't do this, the menubars cover part of the other layouts

Comment: layouts can not contain activities

Comment: Yes, what I mean is to contain other activitie's layouts

Comment: still does not make sense to me. I can not help you if I can not understand what you want to achieve

Comment: please see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19315273/resize-layout-to-get-into-other-layout There I explain a little bit more detailed what I want to do. Not refer to the solution because as you have told me at first, it was wrong

Comment: it is giving now NPE on this line: `inside_menu_view.addView(this_layout);` in the MainClass.java

Comment: sorry if I'm bothering you, but I've post a new question about this where I try to explain best what I need to achieve: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19705485/inflate-a-layout-inside-other-layouts-linearlayout