# Inflate a layout inside other layout's LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, css, android-layout

I've got this Layout:

[ComposeView http://img845.imageshack.us/img845/2121/d6zp.png](http://img845.imageshack.us/img845/2121/d6zp.png)

The 2 borders (left,right )are filled by icons. When I touch one of these icons I access to other activity. The top black bar is a custom title bar.

The clear grey inside space is where I need to fit all activities that I've got on my app. So this layout would be something like a menu layout that would be static in all the activities.

This is the Layout xml:

**menu_view.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout     
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
tools:context="com.example.MenuView" >


<!-- Show top black custom title bar-->
<include 
    layout="@layout/custom_tittlebar" >
</include>


<!-- Button columns -->    
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/lefthandmenu"
    android:layout_width="85dip"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/title"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"       
    android:background="@drawable/border_cut" >

    <ImageView
        ... />
        ...
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/righthandmenu"
    android:layout_width="85dip"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/title"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/border_cut" >

    <ImageView
        ... />
        ...
</LinearLayout>

<!-- Blank space which will contain other activities -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/activitycontent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/righthandmenu"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lefthandmenu"
    android:layout_below="@id/title"
    android:orientation="vertical" >    
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the class where are defined all the icon's onClickListeners.

**MenuView.java**

```
public class MenuView extends RelativeLayout {

private final LayoutInflater inflater;
Context context;

public MenuViewActivity(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    this.context = context;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_view, this, true);


    ((ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.navButton)).setOnClickListener(launch_nav);
}

final OnClickListener launch_nav = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        getContext().startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), Navigation.class));
    }
};
```

Well, having this (I'm not sure if its all ok, maybe I'm doing something wrong with the inflate method or something like this), now the thing would be to define the other activitie's layouts to be inside this view. To do this, I write:

**ExampleActivity.java**

```
public class ExampleActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    LinearLayout inside_menu_view = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.activitycontent);

    View this_layout = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main, inside_menu_view, true);
    inside_menu_view.addView(this_layout);
```

But I'm getting a NullPointerException on this last line. So, something when inflating on this snippets must be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Hey use the following structure. put. include your common layout in each and every activity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


<!-- Show top black custom title bar-->
<include 
    android:id="@+id/ll_top"
    layout="@layout/custom_tittlebar"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
</include>



<include 
    android:id="@+id/ll_left"
    layout="@layout/custom_left"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true" >


</include>
<include 
    android:id="@+id/ll_right"
    layout="@layout/custom_right"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true" >
</include>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_center"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="center"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ll_left"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ll_top"
    ></Button>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thats what I first had. But what I need is the `ExampleActivity's` layout to get gitted inside the LinearLayout `activitycontent`. The way you propose, I used to have almost that way, but I need to have the entire layout inside the menu_view layout

Answer (score 0):

You can have one main activity like BaseActivity that is extended by FragmentActivity. Base activity extends SlidingFragmentActivity and implements basic structure like menu etc. FragmentActivity onCreate method is :

> @Override
>
> ```
> public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>                       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>
>                       fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
>                       //This is main content that is switchable
>                       mContent = new MainListActivity();  
>
>
>                        //Additionally you can define those two lines as fragments and add them as default on both sides :
>                       sideFragments = new sideFragments(this); 
>                       FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
>                       ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, mContent);
>                       ft.replace(R.id.side_framgments, sideFragments);
>                       ft.commit();
>                   }
> ```

When you press some of those buttons from your menu(left and right border) you will change the fragment in middle of the screen with this function in FragmentActivity :

> ```
>   public void switchContent(Fragment fragment, String tag) {
>         mContent = fragment;
>         getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,fragment).addToBackStack(tag).commit(); 
>
>
>   }
> ```

Note `R.id.content_frame` is the XML that is switchable between those two lines (let say menus on both sides) and `R.id.side_framgments` are those two lines in between the main layout that is switchable.