# NPE when inflating layout

Tags: android, android-layout, inflate

I have to set a layout inside other layout's child (linearlayout). To do this, I write this code on the layout's activity that I want to set into the root layout:

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    **setContentView(R.layout.main);**

    /**Define root layout's child where I want to set the layout*/
    LinearLayout inside_menu_view = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.activitycontent);

    /**Inflate this layout and add it to the root layout*/
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View this_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
    inside_menu_view.addView(this_layout);
```

But I'm getting a NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION in this last line `inside_menu_view.addView(this_layout);`

**UPDATE**
-Added the setContentView() after super.onCreate

Comment: where you are calling `setContentView` before accessing `activitycontent` Layout ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєя K I call it after super.onCreate... I updated the post

Comment: @codeMagic No, `activitycontent` is a child of other layout, where I want to insert the `main` layout

Comment: post. stack. trace. and layout main.

Comment: @njzk2 sorry but I don't understand what do you mean

Comment: post your main.xml layout file, and post the complete stacktrace of your exception

Comment: also, something bugs me : you are settings `main` as layout, then inflating it and adding it again inside a view in itself ?

Comment: @njzk2 you can see the full code and what I want to do here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19705485/inflate-a-layout-inside-other-layouts-linearlayout yes, sure that I'm doing lot of thing wrong, I'm newbie with android

Comment: i don't understand what i am looking at. is menu_view named main now ?

Comment: @njzk2 I've got a layout wich consists on 2 borders and a custom title bar called `menu_view`. This layout has a LinearLayout inside of it between the 2 borders and under the titlebar. This layout belongs to a class wich extends RelativeLayout. Then, I've got my Main class (The code snipet above) and the layout that belongs to this class is the `main` and I want to get this into the LinearLayout of the `menu_view`

Comment: then your setcontentview probably should say `setContentView( R.layout.menu_view);`

Comment: I tried with this, and it worked, but I lost the functionality of the buttons, I mean, I couldn't touch the icons and go to other activity

Answer (score 0):

This line will return `null` because you have not yet called `setContentView()`

```
 LinearLayout inside_menu_view = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.activitycontent);
```

You need to call `setContentView(R.layout.layout_with_activitycontent);` first

[From the Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById%28int%29)

> Finds a view that was identified by the id attribute from the XML that was processed in onCreate(Bundle).
>
> Returns The view if found or null otherwise.

You have not yet processed an xml `layout` file with `setContentView()` or by using a `LayoutInflater` so it will `return null` causing a `NPE` when you try to call a method on it like `addView()`.

**Edit**

I'm not sure why you are doing it that way but you can't. As in my link above, you can only use `findViewById()` to find a `View` inside the inflated `layout`. You can't use it to find a `View` inside some other `layout` which hasn't been inflated.

Put that `layout` file in `setContentView()` if that is the one you want to use.

**Different approach**
You probably want to use `Fragments` then to achieve this.

[See the docs on how to use these](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Or you can use `<include>` to include the "menu" `layout` that you want to include in all of the `Activities` then you can switch `Activities` when you need to show the inner part of your `layout`.

[See here about re-using layouts](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)

Example of `<include>`. You have some `layout` that you want to re-use, say `main.xml`, then in an `Activity` in which you want to re-use it you simply do something like

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/blue">
        <include layout="@layout/main"
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <!-- other layouts -->
/<RelativeLayout>
```

yours will obviously be different but this is an example of one I have. Hope this helps.

Comment: updated the post with the place where I've added the setContentView()... but still having the same NPE in the same place

Comment: Did you just add it to your code? If so, try cleaning your project ("Project --> Clean...") and run it again. Also, make sure that `activitycontent` is the `id` of a `LinearLayout` inside `main.xml`.

Comment: as i answered you in the answers above, activitycontent belongs to other different layout

Comment: Yes, I had already commented before I saw your comment. Anyway, see my edit and please don't change code in your OP, it makes it confusing for others.

Comment: just take a look at this, here I explain what I need to achieve an probably you will see it more clear http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19705485/inflate-a-layout-inside-other-layouts-linearlayout

Comment: See my "Different approach" edit. You can't do it the way you are trying. You would need to `inflate` the `layout` which has what you want and add that to the current `layout`. If you know you want it there before runtime then using `<include>` in your `layout` would be much easier.

Comment: I formatted the link, now you could see it. In your last edit of your post, I'm pretty saturated with this, I don't know how to approach it, so, could you be able to edit it getting code from the other post and editing the way you say?

Comment: I have edited with a small example of how to use `<include>` read the link I posted about "re-using layouts" and see that example. I hope it makes sense for you. Give it a try...

Comment: tell if I'm wrong, I've used include but if I want to include lets suppose 10 layouts into the menuview, I would have to set the 10 includes, and how would I select wich one I want to see?

Comment: No, you `<include>` the `layout` with the borders and custom title bar in the other `layout`s

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I had it that way before, but I changed to this way because I needed the other layouts to fit in the blank space inside the menuview layout, and the way I had before, I dind't achieve that, and the borders and the titlebar covered part of the activities that I included. Is there a way to get this not to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your R.layout.main is a LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Now in onCreate():

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View this_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_layout, layout, true);
```

And this_layout is automatically added to the activity's layout.